# Ball Rolling Animation Not Working Properly - Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

For my game, I was trying to achieve ball rolling animation something like this based on finger movement.

[Catch Up (Ketchapp)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SN2fi7_qlXk)

At present, I got success in rolling ball in forwarding direction through right vector rotation so it's looking like we are moving in forwarding direction.

Now based on finger drag, I want to turn the ball on the left and right rotation based on the required measure so I have turned on forward vector rotation but can't able to generate smooth looking rotation in left and right drag.

```
public class BallMeshRolling : MonoBehaviour
{
private Vector3 ballLastPosition;


void Start ()
{
    ballLastPosition = transform.parent.position;
}

void Update ()
{

    // ball moving forward animation
    float rollingSpeed = Vector3.Distance (transform.parent.position, ballLastPosition) * 30f;
    transform.RotateAround (transform.position, Vector3.right, rollingSpeed);

    // ball moving left & right animation
    float dragDifference = (transform.position.x - ballLastPosition.x) * 30f;
    transform.RotateAround (transform.position, Vector3.forward, dragDifference);

    ballLastPosition = transform.parent.position;
}
}
```

As per above code, forward animation running proper but left and right drag rolling animation not working properly so I want some improvements in that.

Comment: define "not working properly"?

Comment: updated question title... thanks